# AngularJS $watch only firing on intitialize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have an angular app that uses d3 to display items, and has an infoPanel that shows the info for items that are clicked on.  This is working, but clicking on the item to activate/open the infopanel is not working.

In the d3 data control file, I have:

```
'use strict';

var settings ;


angular.module('App')
    .directive('data', ['sessionmgmt', 'thedata', 'gui', function (session, data, gui) {
        return {
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

                var promise = angular....getData...;
                promise.then(function () {

                    settings = session.settings;

                    svg = ...

                    createItems(svg, items);
                }, function () {});
            }
        };
  }]);

function createItems(svg, items) {


    let item = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll(".node")
        .data(items, function (d) {
            return d.id;
        });


    appendIcons(item);

}

function appendIcons(nodes){
  nodes = nodes.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");

    nodes.append("title")
      .text(function (d) {
          return d.data['label'];
      });

  nodes.on("click",function(d){
    if(settings.selectedItem === d.id){
      settings.selectedItem = null;
    }else{
      settings.selectedItem = d.id;
    }

  });

}
```

And then in my infoPanel controller I have:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('App')
  .controller('ContentpanelCtrl', ['$scope', 'sessionmgmt', function ($scope, sessionmgmt) {
    var contentPanel = this;

    this.settings = sessionmgmt.settings;

    $scope.activate = function activate() {
      contentPanel.settings.contentPanelOpen = true;
    };


    $scope.getSelected = function getSelected(){
      return contentPanel.settings.itemSelected;
    } 

    $scope.isNodeSelected = function isSelected(){
      return contentPanel.settings.itemSelected !== null;
    } 

    $scope.$watch("contentPanel.settings.itemSelected", function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log(newVal);
      if (newVal !== oldVal){
        $scope.activate();
      }
    });


  }]);
```

The console.log is running when the page first loads, but then when I click on the items, this watch is not being fired.
I know the 'click' is working because getSelected is displaying the correct data on my infopanel. The 'watch' and getSelected are both using exactly the same settings variable....  stumped.

Comment: Add the click function in your controller and add `ng-click`in your html for an item that points to the function. I don't think angular is aware of the change when you do it outside using jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried passing the scope to the `createItems` and then `appendIcons` function and calling `scope.$apply()` after the click event?

Comment: @Razzildinho - that was such great advice! Thank you.  I still haven't got the $watch function working, but don't need to, because my click function now runs `contentPanel.settings.contentPanelOpen = true;` and scope.$apply makes it visible.

Comment: If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this. The first is what I uggested in the comment where you pass the scope of the directive as an argument into the `createItems` and `appendIcons` functions calling `scope.$apply();` in the click event.

From the directive:

```
createItems(svg, items, scope);
```

And the other functions:

```
function createItems(svg, items, scope) {

    let item = svg.append("g")
       /* ... */

    appendIcons(item, scope);

}

function appendIcons(nodes, scope){
    nodes = nodes.enter().append("g")
        /* ... */

    nodes.on("click",function(d){
        if(settings.selectedItem === d.id){
            settings.selectedItem = null;
        }else{
            settings.selectedItem = d.id;
        }
        scope.$apply();
    });

}
```

The other way is to change your `$scope.$watch()` function. The `contentPanel.settings.itemSelected` that you want to watch for is not part of the scope as you are using `this` rather than `$scope`, I assume as part of `controllerAs`. To get the watch working you need to use a function as the first argument in the watch function like the following:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return contentPanel.settings.itemSelected;
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal){
        $scope.activate();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try passing the exact object into the watcher instead of string?

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  if (contentPanel && contentPanel.settings) {
    return contentPanel.settings.itemSelected;
  }
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
  console.log(newVal);
  if (newVal !== oldVal){
    $scope.activate();
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  The first function you recommended doesn't have access to contentPanel... I put console.log(contentPanel.graphSettings);  in that function, and it outputs undefined.

Comment: @FrazerKirkman judging from your updated code, this function should work, for safety I've updated with null check

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean  :(

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to my comment.

In controller:

```
$scope.toggleSelectedItem = function(item) {
   if(contentPanel.settings.itemSelected && 
      contentPanel.settings.itemSelected === item.id){
     contentPanel.settings.itemSelected = null;
   } 
   else {
     contentPanel.settings.itemSelected = item.id;
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="toggleSelectedItem(item)">
   <!--Content-->
</div>
```

Comment: thanks.  My click function is defined in the data control directive file.  The click function doesn't have access to the $scope variable

Comment: Could you post that entire directive please?

Comment: I have included most of the directives file in my questions now.